# Dynamically extract interfaces from silverlight modules and load modules

Tags: reflection, silverlight-4.0, mef, service-locator

In some winforms / webforms applications, I wrote a module that at application start, using reflection, inspects all assemblies from BIN folder, extract all public classes and interfaces they implement and write into a repository. This to to allow me later, at runtime, to load modules based on interfaces they implements and use.

I need to know if / how can I accomplish this for Silverlight. Is there any way to inspect all XAP's and extract all modules together with their metadata? And later to be able to dynamically load the module where the component I need is located, and then load the component from it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code for MEF's `DeploymentCatalog` should show how to inspect the main application XAP as well as download and inspect other XAPs.